# Calling delegate method from popover

Tags: ipad, ios5, popover

I work on a project with ios5, Xcode 4, iPad.

I have a popover triggered from a standard button in my main view. I have setup the popover in the storyboard with a segue anchored to a standard button.

The UIPopoverControllerDelegate is my main view controller

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

When I select a row in the popover I want to

- dismiss the popover and
- call the UIPopoverControllerDelegate method popoverControllerDidDismissPopover.

This is the code in the table view delegate of my popover:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {
     myKey = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
     // [popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover];
```

Without last line, all works OK, row selection and dismission included.

But I am confused with the last line of code

```
     [popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover];
```

If this line is uncommented I get a compiler error: "No known instance method for selector popoverControllerDidDismissPopover". The popover delegate is set in main view controller with this code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender {
     if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[RGBViewController class]]) {
        RGBViewController* viewController = (RGBViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popoverSegue  = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
        [viewController setPopoverController:[popoverSegue popoverController]];
        [[popoverSegue popoverController] setDelegate:self];
     }
 }
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the attribute. The line you are looking for is:

```
[popoverController.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
```

Is there a particular reason you want to call this?  I believe this should be called for you when you dismiss the popover.

Comment: No, when I dismiss the popover programmatically popoverControllerDidDismissPopover is not called. It is only called when the popover is dismissed by the user selecting another element. I have to call popoverControllerDidDismissPopover because contains the action triggered by the popover.

Comment: Ok, well then that should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have a related question. If I have two popover, how can I discriminate in           
    - (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    if (popover1) [self action1]; 
    if (popover2) [self action2]; 
}

Comment: do if (popoverController == popover1) {[self action1];} else if (popoverController == popover2)...